# Executing R scripts in Google Cloud Composer airflow environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I would like to execute an R script from a dag in Google Cloud Composer environment.
How to install R in Composer and run the R script ?

Answer (score 2):

Composer doesn't support installing arbitrary binary packages on the worker pods. The workaround for this is to create a Docker image containing the binary dependency and launch it via [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator).